# Nuxt Content v2 markdown headers rendered as URLs

Tags: html, nuxt.js, markdown, nuxtjs3, nuxt-content

I'm writing Markdown content in Nuxt 3 & Nuxt Content 2.1 and I am facing a problem as I cannot write h2-h6 headers without it rendering them as links.

h1 works fine with one octothorpe symbol but as soon as I add 1 or more of them to render smaller headers, the application automatically transforms them to URLs.

Content is rendered with the default `[...slug].vue` and `<ContentDoc />` configuration as seen in the [documentation](https://content.nuxtjs.org/guide/displaying/rendering).

What's written in Markdown:

```markdown
# header 1

## header 2
```

... and what's actually being rendered in HTML:

```html
<h1 id="header-1">
  <!--[-->
  header 1
  <!--]-->
</h1>

<h2 id="header-2">
  <a href="#header-2">
    <!--[-->
    header 2
    <!--]-->
  </a>
</h2>
```

Is there any way to solve this?

**EDIT:**

Nuxt is also transforming simple HTML `<h2>` tags to links, but now with an undefined `href`:

```html
<h2>header 2</h2>
```

to

```html
<h2>
  <a href="#undefined">
    header 2
  </a>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also change this behaviour in your nuxt.config file

```
content: {
  markdown: {
    anchorLinks: false,
  }
},
```

https://content.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/#anchorlinks

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, with Nick_Ning's answer, you have to change it for every heading tag

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the Nuxt Content doc [here](https://content.nuxtjs.org/guide/writing/markdown/):

> In Nuxt Content, Prose represents the HTML tags output from the Markdown syntax, for example title levels, links... A Vue component corresponds to each tag, allowing you to override them if needed.

By default, h2 becomes <a> tag in <h2> tag, it is defined in [this](https://github.com/nuxt/content/blob/main/src/runtime/components/Prose/ProseH2.vue) file. These files are listed in [components/prose](https://content.nuxtjs.org/api/components/prose/) section.

You may overwrite it by:

1. create **components/content** directory
2. create **ProseH2.vue** in it
3. copy the code from the origin file, in the **template** section, remove the <a> tag and the v-else, or whatever modification you want to do with it:

```
<template>
  <h2 :id="id">
    <slot />
  </h2>
</template>
```

**Restart server**, it should changes.

Comment: this was driving me nuts. your solution saved me. thank you so much.